# Show drop down in Excel cell and remove drop down option from next cell's row if previous row already selected a value from drop down

Tags: excel

Suppose possible values of a drop down included 6, 8, 10, 12, 16, 20, 25.

And I have applied a column's all cells be of list type having above possible drop down values.

Now if user fills first row and selects 6 from down down. When he fills second row the possible drop down values should only show 8, 10, 12, 16, 20, 25. If he selects 10 here the while filling third row the possible drop down values should show 8, 12, 16, 20, 25. Also now if user goes to first row cell then he should be shown 6, 8, 12, 16, 20, 25.

How to change drop down value for each row based on earlier selections?

I have made cell's values to be selected from drop down but all cells are showing all possible values and that is creating redundant rows as there should be max one row with the given possible value.

Comment: So have a list created from the original list excluding the selected value.

Comment: How did you get on with the answers below, Yash?

Answer (score 1):

Something like this:

[image]

The

```
=if(a3<>C$3,A3,"")
```

removes the first selected value, the sort then drops the space to the end.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use helper range for it.

Here is an example filtering out selected number in each subsequent step:

Formula in C4: `=FILTER(C3:I3,(C3:I3<>A3)*(C3:I3<>""))`
for each cell in column A, you need to set validation rule to include current row of the helper range

[image]